# How to find and exec based on python variable in google colab

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, ipython, google-colaboratory

I'm working on [google colaboratory](https://colab.research.google.com/) and i have to do some elaboration to some files based on their extensions, like:

```
!find ./ -type f -name "*.djvu" -exec file '{}' ';'
```

and i expect an output:

```
./file.djvu: DjVu multiple page document
```

but when i try to mix bash and python to use a list of exensions:

```
for f in file_types:
  !echo "*.{f}"
  !find ./ -type f -name "*.{f}" -exec file '{}' ';'
  !echo "*.$f"
  !find ./ -type f -name "*.$f" -exec file '{}' ';'
```

i get only the output of both the `echo` but not of the files.

```
*.djvu
*.djvu
*.jpg
*.jpg
*.pdf
*.pdf
```

If i remove the `exec` part it actually find the files so i can't figure out why the `find` command combined with `exec` fail in some manner.

If needed i can provide more info/examples.

Answer (score 1):

I found an ugly workaround passing trought a file, so first i write the array to a file in python:

```
with open('/content/file_types.txt', 'w') as f:
    for ft in file_types:
      f.write(ft + '\n')
```

and than i read and use it from bash in another cell:

```
%%bash
filename=/content/protected_file_types.txt

while IFS= read -r f;
do
  find ./ -name "*.$f" -exec file {} ';' ;
done < $filename
```

Doing so i dont mix bash and python in the same cell as suggested in the comment of another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61713349/8069500).

I hope to find a better solution that maybe use some trick that I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
declare -a my_array=("pdf" "py")

for i in ${my_array[*]}; do find ./ -type f -name "*.$i" -exec file '{}' ';'; done;
```

Comment: how can i convert the python array in "("pdf" "py")"?

Comment: This is bash not Python, you are probably working from IPython or Jupyter notebook. You can't mix bash and Python like that, even if you could I wouldn't suggest.

Comment: in google colab you can mix bash and python like `files = !find . -type f -name '*.pdf` and `files` will be a python variable.